# Unable to redirect all the HTTP traffic of a network interface to a proxy server

Tags: iptables, proxy

I want to redirect all the HTTP traffic of a network interface (enp0s3) to my proxy server running on `http://*:8080`

These are my network interfaces

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::6291:861b:b4x:c9r3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:fa:5c:69  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12666  bytes 10589141 (10.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5967  bytes 404489 (404.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 153  bytes 13996 (13.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 153  bytes 13996 (13.9 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have tried assigning the following rules on iptables with no success:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any specific reason not to use reverse proxy over NGINX or Apache?

Comment: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/ @DmitriyKupch

Comment: I understand, but wouldn't you like to have more control over your requests?
I am talking about something similar: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: Please tell what does "No success" actually mean? What is the exact action you made? What was the exact result?